# Is there any way to find special characters in a column of a file using grep?

Tags: linux, grep

Is there any way to find special characters in a column of a file using grep?
And line number where the special character is?

Comment: Please give an example of input and expected output.

Comment: `grep` doesn't really have a concept of columns, so I don't think it's the right tool for the job - would you accept `awk` answers?

Answer (score 0):

in general if we say that all alphanumeric characters are actually specials then,

```
grep  '[^[:alnum:] _]' file.txt
```

or more specific one

```
grep -o "\!@#$%^&"
```

you can work on it further